# postgres procedure list of values

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass in a list of values into a Postgres 11 procedure. The query has an `IN` condition. How do I pass in a list of values to the procedure & then how do I use it in the query?

```
create or replace procedure some_procedure(
  source_id_list character varying  <-- is this correct?
  )
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  result_count int;
begin
select count(*)
into result_count
from table sd
where sd.id in source_id_list  <-- syntax error
;
RAISE NOTICE 'result: %', result_count;
end;
$$
```

Comment: `IN` accepts a list of values, you are giving it a string. Why not use an array as an argument to the function instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` expects a list of values, while you are giving it a string.

If you can change the datatype of the argument to the procedure, then it would be simpler to use an array:

```
create or replace procedure some_procedure(source_id_list int[])
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    result_count int;
begin
    select count(*)
    into result_count
    from table sd
    where id = any(source_id_list);
    
    raise notice 'result: %', result_count;
end;
$$
```

If you can't change the argument of the datatype, then another option uses `string_to_array()` to parse the string as an array:

```
select count(*)
into result_count
from table sd
where sd.id = any(string_to_array(source_id_list, ',')::int[]);
```

Comment: those are great solutions. how do I pass in a list? in my case, the ids are strings, `  source_id_list character varying[] := ('5f697ecb9ddf7744a7a1f935');` gives me error: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "5f697ecb9ddf7744a7a1f935"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
thanks

Comment: @FooL: `ARRAY['5f697ecb9ddf7744a7a1f935']`